Two schedulers not working as expected in spring boot application
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void getResetSiteEvents() {
        log.info("===ResetService Scheduler started ===");
        List<String> siteIds = branchRepository.getSiteIds();
        LocalDateTime startDate = LocalDateTime.now().minusSeconds(5);
        LocalDateTime stopDate = LocalDateTime.now();
        SiteEventReq requestPayload = CommonService.createSiteEventRequest(startDate, stopDate, false, true);

        if(requestPayload.isEctReset()) {
            for (String siteId : siteIds) {
                executorService.submit(() -> {
                    log.info("Sending request for site ID: {}", siteId);
                    try {
                        String response = sendRequest(siteId, requestPayload);
                        List<SiteEventResp> siteEventResponses = parseResponse(response);
                        if (siteEventResponses != null && !siteEventResponses.isEmpty()) {
                            log.info("Reset Responses: {}", siteId);
                            checkDbForClosedAlarms(siteEventResponses);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        log.error("Error sending request for site ID " + siteId + ": " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void getSiteEvents() {
        log.info("===AlarmService Scheduler started ===");
        List<String> siteIds = branchRepository.getSiteIds();
        LocalDateTime startDate = LocalDateTime.now().minusSeconds(5);
        LocalDateTime stopDate = LocalDateTime.now();
        SiteEventReq requestPayload = CommonService.createSiteEventRequest(startDate, stopDate, true, false);

        if(requestPayload.isEctAlarm()) {
            for (String siteId : siteIds) {
                executorService.submit(() -> {
                    log.info("Sending request for site ID: {}", siteId);
                    try {
                        String response = sendRequest(siteId, requestPayload);
                        List<SiteEventResp> siteEventResponses = parseResponse(response);
                        if (siteEventResponses != null && !siteEventResponses.isEmpty()) {
                            log.info("Alarm Responses: {}", siteId);
                            saveSiteEvents(siteEventResponses);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        log.error("Error sending request for site ID " + siteId + ": " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

 private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

I have 2 shcedulers in Spring Boot application.
In threory i expect 5 site ids from the request below:
List<String> siteIds = branchRepository.getSiteIds();
That's why i use newFixedThreadPool to send 5 requests simutaneously, at the same time.
I expect the first scheduler to return 'reset' responses, and second one 'alarm' responses.
When I run the application I expect alarm reponses to print the log in the relevant alarm scheduler, like below:
log.info("Alarm Responses: {}", siteId);
So i only expect here alarm responses.
The problem is it prints reset responses as well. I can't seem to understand why, it should not print reset responses.
In reset scheduler it is the same. It should only print reset responses, but instead it prints alarm responses as well.
There is no error messages by the way.
Is there anybody that knows why it happens and how can i fix that?
I have condition before for loop:
alarm scheduler --> if(requestPayload.isEctAlarm())
reset scheduler --> if(requestPayload.isEctReset())
if(requestPayload.isEctAlarm()) {
            for (String siteId : siteIds) {
                executorService.submit(() -> {
                    log.info("Sending request for site ID: {}", siteId);
                    try {
                        String response = sendRequest(siteId, requestPayload);
                        List<SiteEventResp> siteEventResponses = parseResponse(response);
                        if (siteEventResponses != null && !siteEventResponses.isEmpty()) {
                            log.info("Alarm Responses: {}", siteId);
                            saveSiteEvents(siteEventResponses);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        log.error("Error sending request for site ID " + siteId + ": " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }
        }

